# How to setup PC to only access specific website from WIFI and all other things from Ethernet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, ethernet

Suppose network interface 1 (net1) and 2 (net2) are both connected to the Internet. I want Firefox or any browser to use WIFI (net2) to access only YouTube, and For every other thing to use Ethernet (net1). How can it be done under Windows 10?

If you need a concrete example of the above situation, consider:

```
A Desktop with Windows 10
net1 = A wired connection to a Router
net2 = A wireless connection tethered to this Desktop from my Phone
```

I want to do this because I have a unlimited YouTube streaming package activated on my phone and Ethernet has a limited bandwidth per month.

Comment: Which network adapter is used for sending an IP packet is determined by the configured routes and the default gateway. You can configure own routes using the command-line tool `route`.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be via the router by assigning static IPs to each adapter's MAC on the router, then creating firewall rules for the WiFi static IP and MAC to only allow access to `youtube.com` and other YouTube domains [e.g. `youtu.be`], blocking all other WAN access. Firewall rules are hierarchical, so once the YouTube rules are created, the next should be blocking all traffic to the WAN interface/WAN firewall zone.